# Formatting a Stata table like a table in SAS

Tags: sas, stata

I have a 3-way table in Stata that looks like this:
[image]

I would like to format this 3-way crosstab like a table in SAS that looks like this:
[image]

The actual output in the table isn't important, I just want to know how I can change the formatting of the Stata table. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's better to show images as such, not as links.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1575424-formatting-a-3-way-stata-table-like-a-sas-table It's best to tell people about cross-posting.

Answer (score 2):

The `groups` command from the *Stata Journal* will get you most of the way. This reproducible example doesn't exhaust the possibilities.

```
. webuse nlswork, clear
(National Longitudinal Survey.  Young Women 14-26 years of age in 1968)

. groups union race , show(f F p P) sepby(union)

  +--------------------------------------------------+
  | union    race   Freq.     #<=   Percent      %<= |
  |--------------------------------------------------|
  |     0   white   10777   10777     56.02    56.02 |
  |     0   black    3784   14561     19.67    75.69 |
  |     0   other     167   14728      0.87    76.56 |
  |--------------------------------------------------|
  |     1   white    2817   17545     14.64    91.20 |
  |     1   black    1649   19194      8.57    99.77 |
  |     1   other      44   19238      0.23   100.00 |
  +--------------------------------------------------+
```

The command must be installed before you can use it. `groups` is a lousy search term, but this `search` will find the 2017 write-up and later updates of the software (at the time of writing, just one in 2018).

```
. search st0496, entry

Search of official help files, FAQs, Examples, and Stata Journals

SJ-18-1 st0496_1  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Software update for groups
        (help groups if installed)  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q1/18   SJ 18(1):291
        groups exited with an error message if weights were specified;
        this has been corrected

SJ-17-3 st0496  . . . . .  Speaking Stata: Tables as lists: The groups command
        (help groups if installed)  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q3/17   SJ 17(3):760--773
        presents command for listing group frequencies and percents and
        cumulations thereof; for various subsetting and ordering by
        frequencies, percents, and so on; for reordering of columns;
        and for saving tabulated data to new datasets
```